# Listview cursor adapter, always get first item onClicked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-adapter

I have this piece of code for listview using simple cursor adapter :

```
final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.textonly_listview_item, cursor, from, to);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Cursor item = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        view.setSelected(true);
        G.t(getActivity(), "Now working with category: " + item.getName());
    }
});
```

when clicked whichever cell, it always get the first item or the top most item in list view, can some one tell me where i am wrong?

[image: Screenshoot sample]

Comment: What if you move `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to the end (after the toast)? Does it change anything?

Comment: Wops, it is work like magic, move your comment to answer so i can upvote and mark it as correct ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you should move the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to the end.  That is the probable reason why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
Cursor item = adapter.getItem(position);
view.setSelected(true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```